# Aumentar espaço entre palavras para ocupar o width da div?

Tags: jquery, css

Eu tenho um texto que eu gostaria de "esticar", ou seja, deixar espaçamento entre letras até que chegue ao fim da `div`, existe alguma forma de o fazer? A `div` tem de ter `height` estática. Posso usar tanto `Jquery` como `CSS`.

Já procurei em vários sítios mas eu via apenas aumentar o `font-size` mas não é isso que pretendo.

Comment: Quando você diz "esticar", você se refere a altura ou largura?

Comment: Largura, porque tal como referi, não queria alterar o height

Comment: Existe um *hack* com o elemento `after`: https://jsfiddle.net/trp2ck2h/1/. É disso que precisa?

Comment: Talvez este algoritmo te ajude: [http://jsfiddle.net/DMw6Z/](http://jsfiddle.net/DMw6Z/), ajusta a propriedade `letter-spacing` conforme a largura do elemento pai (`parent`).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É exatamente isso que necessitava! Adicione como resposta e será aceite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem os elementos "letter-spacing" para largura, o "line-height" para altura e o "word-spacing" para espaço nas palavras no css, não sei se é exatamente isso que você quer:

```css
p {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    word-spacing: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Eu tenho um texto que eu gostaria de "esticar", ou seja, deixar espaçamento entre letras até que chegue ao fim da div, existe alguma forma de o fazer? A div tem de ter height estática. Posso usar tanto Jquery como CSS.</p>
```

Comment: Eu queria que a frase com cerca de 4 palavras ocupasse 1 só linha.

Comment: você tem um exemplo?

Comment: A resposta do Anderson servirá de exemplo.